# APEX and older ECMAScript versions

Tags: javascript, apex, ecmascript-2020

Is there a way to force APEX to use older ECMAScript standard during the minification of its .js code?
We are using the version of APEX that uses the optional chaining operator '?.' during the JS minification, but this operator isn't supported in browsers released prior to year 2020. and this type of compatibility is important to us.

Comment: Not familiar with Apex, so there may be a cleaner solution, but you could always run the output JavaScript through Babel.